# Permutations in a Phrase

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What are the different anagrams of the word GRAMMIKH*ALGEBRA? The star can be considered as a character and may be at the beginning or end of the sentence. Find out how many different phrases they can be, even if some of them do not make sense in English. Two phrases are considered different if a different character is presented in at least one position.

I figured it out as a permutations problem. However I see repeated characters in the sentence, so is it a repeated permutations problem?
I would appreciate for your quidance.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If there are repeated characters, you need to divide the number of all permutation by the number of permutations of a single character, for all characters. For example, I can rearrange $aabbb$ into $5!$ words, but I need to divide by $2!$ since $a$ is repeated 2 times, and divide again by $3!$ since $b$ is repeated 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $15$ letters and one symbol $ *$ , so there are  $16$ objects and there are $16!$ permutation of them , but there are repeated letters , so they should be considered.(We use division rule to handle repeated letters)

Then $\frac {16!}{2! \times 3! \times 2! \times 2!}=435891456000$ where $3A,2R,2G,2M$

NOTE: If $*$ can only be   either in beginnging or end ,then the answer is  $  \frac {15!}{2! \times 3! \times 2! \times 2!} \times 2$

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!

Comment: @Vasilis you are welcome :)) have a nice day

Comment: @Vasilis ıf this question solved your problem , you should accept this answer.Otherwise . it will be thought that you want more answers